# UserManager.GetUserAsync always returns null

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication

I've created an API controller in my ASP.NET Core project. I want to get some info about the user. This controller has a public constructor with a `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` as a parameter.

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public GetSteamID(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

In a Get function I'm trying to get the user using `GetUserAsync` and it always returns null regardles if a user has logged on. I've also tried to get it using a user ID (or subject ID) and had no luck either.

```
ApplicationUser currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

My Startup.cs file looks like this

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddSteam()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Ryhon,By default,if the user login and currentUser could not be null.Please share your Startup.cs to show how did you configure Identity.

Comment: @Rena I've added the Startup.cs functions

Comment: Hi @Ryhon,please check if your token has been passed to the core project successfully by using Fiddler.